# Input Messages in Discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, discord.py

I'm trying to find a way to program my bot to clear a specific amount of messages in a channel. However, I do not know how to get my bot to run it's code based on the user's input data. For example, let's say I'm a user who wants to clear a specific amount of messages, like let's say 15 messages. I want my bot to then clear 15 messages exactly, no more, no less. How do I do that?

```
    if message.content == "{clear":
    await message.channel.send("Okay")
    await message.channel.send("How many messages should I clear my dear sir?")
```

This is legit all I got lmao. I'm sorry that I'm such a disappointment to this community ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `on_message` event, you'd have to use the [`startswith`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/startswith) mehtod and create a `amount` variable which takes your message content without `{clear`  as a value:

```py
if message.content.startswith("{clear"):
    amount = int(message.content[7:])
    await message.channel.purge(limit=amount+1)
```

However, I don't recommend using `on_message` events to create commands. You could use the [`commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) framework of discord.py. It will be much easier for you to create commands.
A quick example:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='{')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot's ready to go")

@bot.command(name="clear")
async def clear(ctx, amount: int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount+1)

bot.run("Your token")
```

[`ctx`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context) will allow you to access the message `author`, `channel`, `guild`, ... and will allow you to call methods such as `send`, ...